# SQL match and extract keywords

Tags: sql, match, palantir-foundry

I have a column of 52 words contained in a table  ‘key_word’ and I’m searching for those words in the narrative column.  The narrative column in a table ‘ssn_match_date' which  has about 30k records of narrative text. How do I make this not case sensitive?

```
    SELECT a.*, b.word
    FROM  key_word  b  inner join ssn_match_date a 
    on a.narrative like concat('%', b.word, '%')
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, along with a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] your tags to add one for the type of table server you use: mysql? sql-server? postgresql? And please tell us what you mean, exactly, by "crashed."

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm running the sql statement in palantir-foundry

Comment: `a` and `b` are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like `kw` for `key_word`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. Matches keyword list to text narrative rows containing those keywords. I just lower cased the words to get all the matches regardless of case.

```
SELECT a.*, b.word
FROM  key_word  b  inner join ssn_match_date a 
on lower(a.narrative) like concat('%', lower(b.word), '%')
```